# Invalid character Error on replace?

Tags: javascript, replace

I am getting an invalid character error in Opera (haven't tested in other browsers) on a page, and brings up this line of code:

```
x.description.replace(/([a-zA-Z]|\)+/, "").replace(/(\+r|\+b[0-9]+)/, ".").split(".")
```

The invalid character is pointing to the comma in this specific code:  `/([a-zA-Z]|\)+/, ""`

Why is the comma an invalid character?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first regex, you are missing the closing `)` to terminate the group:

```
/([a-zA-Z]|\)+)/
```